# Blackberry 10 Cascades: setting textStyle.lineHeight on Label clips text

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have the following QML (Hosted in a TabbedPane, if that could possibly make any difference):

```
Container {
    Label {
        text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        multiline: true
        textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.XLarge
        textStyle.lineHeight: 0.8
        textStyle.color: Color.Black
    }
}
```

Setting the textStyle.lineHeight property to something less than 1.0 does what I expect, except that the bottom line of text in the label is clipped at the bottom.  Any ideas how to work around this, or if I'm doing something wrong?

Screenshot of results, from a Dev Alpha B device running OS 10.0.9.348.  Results look the same on the 10.1 simulator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Helpful folks at the Blackberry forum answered this for me.

The workaround is to add a "\n" to the end of the label text.  This fixes the clipping, but adds extra space under the label.  We can work around this problem then by setting a negative bottomPadding value on the wrapping Container.